# object to arbitrary faces

Tags: mesh

Is it possible to place a monkey on checkboxed faces? There are only 12 marked faces, but it can be arbitrary (50 and more).
An example of the desired result is on the left.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Since no-one else has answered, there's a YT video which shows how to use instances to add a single object to multiple faces [here](https://youtu.be/mrJhbjVfcGY?t=888) which might give you some ideas. In this case it's for every face of a single object  but I guess it should be possible to use Geometry nodes to add to selected faces of multiple objects although that's not something I can help with.